# Memory and CPU usage definition in docker cadvisor

Tags: memory, docker, cpu-usage, memory-consumption, cadvisor

How can you define the memory usage metric provided by google cadvisor in docker? 
Is it dynamic stack size, heap requirement, cache misses, code size, swap memory or RAM memory? 
as well for cpu cumulative usage, in which measure unit it is calculated? How can you define it?
Is there any documentation on that ?

NB: I recall that cadvisor container export resource usage data to influxDB. Among the metrics that he is exporting there is: memory_usage, cpu_cumulative_usage, among others...

Thank you